Wanting to hang framed posters on what I believe are plaster walls
As the title suggests, I’m looking to hang three separate framed movie posters. Each of the framed posters weighs roughly 12 lbs. maybe 15 max. The house itself was built in the 1920’s and when combined with the fact that my stud finder isn’t able to find a stud, I assume it is plaster and lath. Tried a pushpin in hopes of doing an easy test. Pushpin didn’t even really scratch it.
I marked out where we hoped to hang them and then began by drilling tiny holes to see if I could find a good spot to get them hung. Each of the holes I attempted went through pretty easily until a certain point. But I couldn’t tell for sure if I was just drilling the small holes into plaster or if I was getting to the lath. So I drilled a bigger one to actually get a look into the wall.
As I began drilling, I realized that the wood seemed considerably further back than my last house I lived in that also had plaster and lath walls.
My question is really just how do I hang anything up when the wood starts almost 3/4” into the wall? I’ve had success with toggle bolts in the past, but it didn’t feel the same way the walls do here. It felt like there was a lot more resistance drilling into this lath than the last house which scared me and made me fearful of continuing to drill into it.
I attached a couple of images in hopes that they might clear things up a bit, but if not, I’m more than happy to answer any follow-up questions that any of you may need answered in order to give me a more specific answer to my question!
Thank you to anyone who took the time to read this and answers! My fiancée will appreciate me finally getting these posters hung since my anxiety about hanging things off plaster walls has kept me from really getting in here to do it.



If there's wood, what's wrong with screws of one variety or another?

Wouldn’t normal screws likely cause cracks in the plaster?

If you're worried about cracks, you drill a hole through the plaster, but not into the wood.

I use following type on my drywalls.
So far they worked well without failure.
Pre-drill not greater that the neck, then just screw in with Philips screwdriver.
Found in many stores like this one
drywall

